# How can I add a password between tabs on powershell GUI

Tags: powershell

I am creating a GUI that contains 2 tabs.
Each tab contains buttons that will run a specific action.

I want to separate the tabs by password, then team1 will be able to access only tab1 and team 2 will be able to access tab1 and tab2.

This is the tab part from my code:

```
        #------------[TAB1]------------
        $Tab1 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.Tabpage
        $Tab1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
        $Tab1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True 
        $Tab1.Name = "Team1" 
        $Tab1.Text = "TAB1"
        $FormTabControl.Controls.Add($Tab1)

        #------------[TAB2]------------
        $Tab2 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.Tabpage
        $Tab2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0 
        $Tab2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True 
        $Tab2.Name = "Team2" 
        $Tab2.Text = "TAB2"
        $FormTabControl.Controls.Add($Tab2)
```

Thank you

Comment: I doubt this is possible. It wouldn't do much good, anyway. What's to stop someone from team 1 just opening the PowerShell script, removing the password, and then running the script? Or opening the script, reading the password, and then running the script and entering it?

Comment: I am changing the ps1 to a exe file, so the team1 cannot change the code. I just wanted to restrict some buttons for each team.

Comment: You could make each tab a [`SplitContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer) where the content is in Panel2, but set Panel2 as [collapsed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel2collapsed). Then in Panel1 have a [`MaskedTextBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox) as password with [PasswordChar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.passwordchar). If the password is correct, set Panel2Collapse = $false.

Comment: Consider another design approach. Check user group memberships, and populate tab contents only if they match with respective team groups.

Comment: @Brazs With the exe it might be harder to change the code, but the password(s) can still be read.

Comment: Thank you everyone!! I understand that it is not a secure method, but since it is for a non-sensitive data, I will try to use the information from @jeremywat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you can create a [`SplitContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer) with one panel essentially only containing a password entry box, and the other panel containing the content to display. Have the content panel hidden and only display it if the correct password is entered.

Example:

```
using namespace System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Create form
$Form = [Form]@{
    AutoSize = $true
    MinimumSize = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(150,150)
    AcceptButton = [System.Windows.Forms.IButtonControl]::ok
    CancelButton = [System.Windows.Forms.IButtonControl]::Cancel
}

# Create tab control
$FormTabControl = [System.Windows.Forms.TabControl] @{ Dock = 'Fill' }

# Create tab 1
$Tab1 = [TabPage] @{
    Dock = 'Fill'
    UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
    Name = "Team1"
    Text = "TAB1"
}
$Tab1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0

# Create split container for tab 1. Panel1 will contain the password entry and panel2 will contain the content.
$Tab1SplitContainer = [SplitContainer] @{
    Dock = 'Fill'
    Panel2Collapsed = $true
    Orientation = 'Horizontal'
}

# Create top down flow panel for tab 1 to arrange the password/enter box above the "invalid password" error.
$Tab1Panel1TopDownFlowPanel = [FlowLayoutPanel] @{
    Dock = 'Fill'
    FlowDirection = 'TopDown'
    AutoSize = $true
    Anchor = 'Left'
}

# Error text to display when invalid password is entered.
$Tab1PassowrdError = [System.Windows.Forms.Label] @{
    Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(100, 20)
    Text = "Invalid password"
    ForeColor = 'Red'
    Visible = $false
}

# Left to right flow panel to arrange the "enter" button to the right of the password box.
$Tab1Panel1LeftRightFlowPanel = [FlowLayoutPanel] @{
    Dock = 'Fill'
    FlowDirection = 'LeftToRight'
    AutoSize = $true
    Anchor = 'Left'
}

# Password box. The password character is * to hide text when entering.
$Tab1MaskedTextBox = [MaskedTextBox] @{
    PasswordChar = '*'
    Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(100, 20)
}

# Button for submitting the password.
$Tab1Button = [Button] @{ Text = 'Enter' }
# Script to run when the button is clicked.
$Tab1Button.Add_Click({
    # If the password is valid (matches 'password'), close the password panel and open the content panel.
    if ($Tab1MaskedTextBox.Text -eq 'password'){
        $Tab1SplitContainer.Panel1Collapsed = $true
        $Tab1SplitContainer.Panel2Collapsed = $false
    } else {
        # If not, display the invalid password error
        $Tab1PassowrdError.Visible = $true
    }
})

# Add the above controls to the respective containers
$Tab1Panel1LeftRightFlowPanel.Controls.AddRange(@($Tab1MaskedTextBox, $Tab1Button))
$Tab1Panel1TopDownFlowPanel.Controls.AddRange(@($Tab1Panel1LeftRightFlowPanel, $Tab1PassowrdError))
$Tab1SplitContainer.Panel1.Controls.Add($Tab1Panel1TopDownFlowPanel)

# Top down flow layout for displaying the content on panel 2
$Tab1Panel2TopDownFlowPanel = [FlowLayoutPanel] @{
    Dock = 'Fill'
    FlowDirection = 'TopDown'
    AutoSize = $true
    Anchor = 'Left'
}

# Content label
$Tab1Panel2Label = [System.Windows.Forms.Label] @{
    Text = "Content here"
    Size = [System.Drawing.Size]::new(100, 20)
}

# Add remaining controls to their respective containers
$Tab1Panel2TopDownFlowPanel.Controls.Add($Tab1Panel2Label)
$Tab1SplitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add($Tab1Panel2TopDownFlowPanel)
$Tab1.Controls.Add($Tab1SplitContainer)
$FormTabControl.Controls.Add($Tab1)
$Form.Controls.Add($FormTabControl)

# Display the form
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Repeat for each tab.

Form:

[image]

After invalid password:

[image]

After valid password:

[image]

As others have mentioned, this isn't a very secure method but it's doable for non-sensitive data.

Comment: Thank you!! I will try to follow your explanation and adjust to my GUI